# nlsLM & nls issue: "singular gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates"

Tags: r, nls

I have problems solving a **non linear equation**.
I had tried using **nls** and **nlsLM**.

Given this example, extracted from **stats::nls**:

```
library(minpack.lm)
x <- -(1:100)/10
y <- 100 + 10 * exp(x / 2+40)
```

I'm trying to solve a equation like:

```
y ~  Const + A * exp(B * x + C)
```

If I try with:

```
nlmod <- nlsLM(y ~  Const + A * exp(B * x + C),start=list(Const=100,A=10,B=.5,C=40))
```

I get:

```
Error in nlsModel(formula, mf, start, wts) : 
  singular gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates
```

If try removing "C", with:

```
nlmod <- nlsLM(y ~  Const + A * exp(B * x),start=list(Const=100,A=10,B=.5)); summary(nlmod)
```

I get a result... but as we know from the definition, is **not perfect**:

```
Formula: y ~ Const + A * exp(B * x)

Parameters:
       Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
Const 1.000e+02  1.444e+17       0        1
A     1.000e+01  3.471e+17       0        1
B     5.000e-01  3.654e+16       0        1

Residual standard error: 7.369e+17 on 97 degrees of freedom

Number of iterations to convergence: 1 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 1.49e-08
```

I also had tried using **nls**, with almost the same result:

```
> nlmod <- nls(y ~  Const + A * exp(B * x+ C),start=list(Const=100,A=10,B=.5,C=40))
Error in nlsModel(formula, mf, start, wts) : 
  singular gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates

> nlmod <- nls(y ~  Const + A * exp(B * x),start=list(Const=100,A=10,B=.5)); summary(nlmod)
Error in nls(y ~ Const + A * exp(B * x), start = list(Const = 100, A = 10,  : 
  singular gradient
```

Thanks for your insights.

Comment: Any software will fail with this since your model is over-parameterized. Either fix A to 1 or C to 0.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, thank you for making me notice: `x^n*x^m=x^(n+m)` http://faculty.headroyce.org/~sclark/Algebra%20Unit%204%20(Ch.%208)/Properties%20of%20Exponents/MultPropOfExponents.html